# Yii2-advanced : dataProvider

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I want to increment my dataProvider in siteController. That  is, at each iteration, my dataProvider should be incremented by 1 & renamed as dataProvider1,dataProvider2,dataProvider3,....& so on.
I tried to append $i to dataProvider, but it says 'dataProvider can't be converted to String...!'

My actionIndex is as follows :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
        $query = new \yii\db\Query;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
            $query->select('*')->from('business_main_categories')->where(['bmc_id' => $i]);
            $query->createCommand();

            $dataProvider.$i = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $query,
                'pagination' => false,
            ]);

            return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider.$i,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

And, I also want to user that dataProvider in my 'index.php' with iterations; I tried to insert a for loop & written all statements in 'echo', but I'm unable to get it done.

My way to access it in 'index.php' is as follows :

```
<?= GridView::widget([
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'summary' => '',
                        'columns' => [
                                [
                                    'attribute' => 'bmc_image',
                                    'format' => 'html',
                                    'label' => '',
                                    'value' => function ($data) {
                                        return Html::img($data['bmc_image'],
                                            ['width' => '190px']);
                                    },
                                ],
                            ]
                   ]); ?>
```

Please help me to solve my issue.

Comment: Could you explain, why you need 20 data providers?

Comment: I've to retrieve 20 records from my database.

Comment: In this case you don't need 20 data providers. You need one 1 provider with according query.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want. But I've to iterate the above code of a gridview in my index.php , to manage 20 records in a single loop.

Comment: I'm able to get all 20 records in dataProvider by doing some changes in actionIndex. But then, problem is in how to iterate them in a gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem without using gridview. As follows -

My SiteController -

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new BusinessMainCategoriesSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = $dataProvider->getTotalCount();   //-1 : disable

        return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

using this code I get all records in dataProvider from my db.
(Note that, I'm using ActiveDataProvider in my 'BusinessMainCategoriesSearch' model)

And, my index.php is -

```
<?php
                    $m = $dataProvider->getModels();
                    foreach ($m as $dp) {
                    echo "<img src = '".$dp['bmc_image']."' />";
                    echo '<center><font color = "white">'.$dp['bmc_name'].'<font/></center>';

        } ?>
```

It worked great for me & it's a easiest way to do so.